# How to initialize an object with Roslyn

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

I've really tried to solve this on my own, and it seems so simple but hopefully with the right pointer I can work out the rest of what I need, but...

How can I generate the following code with Rosyln:

```
var entity = new Entity
{
    Name = "A",
    Value = 12
};
```

I know `SyntaxFactory.InitializerExpression` is involved somewhere, but I'm just lost!

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: This is kinda why the syntax visualizer exists in the first place. Install it... use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Roslyn Quoter tool is very handy for things like this:

[roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/).

Now that it assumes you have an entire valid file

Comment: How come I've never heard of this.. This is incredibly useful to see how these things are built up.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you!! And it turns out, the Roslyn code needed for my simple statement is gargantuan..!!

Comment: Myyyyyy precioussssssss.